# how to fix error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I feel as if I am missing something really simple but I can't find it. 
The goal of this code is to take a Shakespeare file and use a hash map to find the number of times a word is given by the text as well as words of "n" characters long. However I can't even get to the debugging portion because I get the error

```
Bard.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
     Pattern getout = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+"); //this will take only the words
     ^   symbol:   class Pattern   location: class Bard
Bard.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
     Pattern getout = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+"); //this will take only the words
```

plus a few more location. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bard {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap < String, Integer > m1 = new HashMap < String, Integer > (); // sets the hashmap

    //create file reader for the shakespere text
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("shakespeare.txt"))) {
      String line = br.readLine();
      Pattern getout = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+"); //this will take only the words 

      //create the hashmap
      while (line != null) {
        Matcher m = getout.matcher(line); //find the relevent information

        while (m.find()) {
          if (m1.get(m.group()) == null && !m.group().toUpperCase().equals(m.group())) { //find new word that is not in all caps.
            m1.put(m.gourp(), 1);
          } else { //increments the onld word
            int newValue = m1.get(m.group());
            newValue++;
            m1.put(m.group, newValue);
          }
        }
        line = br.readLine();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try (BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
      String line2 = br2.readLine();
      FileWriter output = new FileWriter("analysis.txt");

      while (line2 != null) {

        if (line2.matches("[\\d\\s]+")) { // if i am dealing with the two integers 
          String[] args = line.split(" "); // split them up
          wordSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // set the first on the the word size
          numberOfWords = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // set the other one to the number of words wanted
          String[] wordsToReturn = new String[numberOfWords]; //create array to place the words
          int i = 0;
          int j;
          for (String word: m1.keySet()) { //  
            if (word.length() == wordSize) {
              wordToReturn[i] = word;
              i++;
            }


            for (j = 0; numberOfWords > j; j++) {
              output.write(wordToReturn[j]);
            }
          }
        } else {
          output.write(m1.get(line2));
        }


      }
      line2 = br2.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not imported the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. Import it with :-

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```